# How can I extract managment-ip and hostname from the uri?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

The playbook below is designed to use uri module to make a call to a device and extract hostnames and ip addresses. This part is working as designed.The next step is what I am struggling with. I am able to save the output to a register but I am unable to pull it apart looking for hostnames/ip addresses.

Here is the playbook.

```yaml
---
- name: Step - 1.1 - Find management_ips
  uri:
      url: 'https://{{ ansible_host}}/mgmt/shared/resolver/device-groups/cm-bigip-allBigIpDevices/devices?$select=mcpDeviceName,managementAddress'
      user: "{{ansible_admin}}"
      password: "{{ansible_pass}}"
      method: GET
      body: '{"include": "none"}'
      headers:
        Content-Type: application/json
        return_content: yes
      validate_certs: false
  register: mgmtip

- name: display inventory
  debug:
    var: mgmtip.json
```

This is how the debug output appears.

```yaml
  mgmtip:
    ansible_facts:
      discovered_interpreter_python: /usr/bin/python
    cache_control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
    changed: false
    connection: close
    content_length: '32060'
    content_type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    cookies: {}
    cookies_string: ''
    date: Fri, 07 Apr 2023 21:40:33 GMT
    elapsed: 0
    expires: '-1'
    failed: false
    json:
      generation: 217835
      items:
      - managementAddress: 10.1.2.91
        mcpDeviceName: /Common/ijkllab101.cis.mytest.net
      - managementAddress: 10.1.2.221
        mcpDeviceName: /Common/mnoplab104.cis.mytest.net
      - managementAddress: 10.1.2.221
        mcpDeviceName: /Common/abcddevlab0201.cis.mytest.net
      - managementAddress: 10.1.2.21
        mcpDeviceName: /Common/ijkldevlab0201.cis.mytest.net
      - managementAddress: 10.1.2.88
        mcpDeviceName: /Common/qrstdevlab0201.cis.mytest.net
      - managementAddress: 10.1.2.57
        mcpDeviceName: /Common/bigip1
      - managementAddress: 10.1.2.223
        mcpDeviceName: /Common/efghdevlab0201.cis.mytest.net
      - managementAddress: 10.1.9.123
...
```

This is what I have tried to extract the managementAddress with no success. Also, I have tried several variations of this looking for the mcpDeviceName, again with no success

```yaml
- name: Create int dict
  set_fact:
    managementinterfaces: "{{ mgmtip.json.managementAddress }}"

- name: Display management address
  debug:
    var: managementinterfaces
```

I have tried several other iterations of this last step looking for Management IP address and the Device name with no success. Any help you can provide around how to extract managementAddress and mcpDeviceName would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [`...with no success` is not an accurate description of the issue you are facing](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the [*bracket notation*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables) because *items* is name of a method

```yaml
  mgmt_interfaces: "{{ mgmtip.json['items']|
                       map(attribute='managementAddress')|
                       list }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  mgmt_interfaces:
  - 10.1.2.91
  - 10.1.2.221
  - 10.1.2.221
  - 10.1.2.21
  - 10.1.2.88
  - 10.1.2.57
  - 10.1.2.223
```

To simplify searching you can create a dictionary

```yaml
  name_addr: "{{ mgmtip.json['items']|
                 items2dict(key_name='mcpDeviceName',
                            value_name='managementAddress') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  name_addr:
    /Common/abcddevlab0201.cis.mytest.net: 10.1.2.221
    /Common/bigip1: 10.1.2.57
    /Common/efghdevlab0201.cis.mytest.net: 10.1.2.223
    /Common/ijkldevlab0201.cis.mytest.net: 10.1.2.21
    /Common/ijkllab101.cis.mytest.net: 10.1.2.91
    /Common/mnoplab104.cis.mytest.net: 10.1.2.221
    /Common/qrstdevlab0201.cis.mytest.net: 10.1.2.88
```

Then you get the list of the addresses also as a list of the values

```yaml
  mgmt_interfaces: "{{ name_addr.values()|list }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    mgmtip:
      ansible_facts:
        discovered_interpreter_python: /usr/bin/python
      cache_control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
      changed: false
      connection: close
      content_length: '32060'
      content_type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
      cookies: {}
      cookies_string: ''
      date: Fri, 07 Apr 2023 21:40:33 GMT
      elapsed: 0
      expires: '-1'
      failed: false
      json:
        generation: 217835
        items:
        - managementAddress: 10.1.2.91
          mcpDeviceName: /Common/ijkllab101.cis.mytest.net
        - managementAddress: 10.1.2.221
          mcpDeviceName: /Common/mnoplab104.cis.mytest.net
        - managementAddress: 10.1.2.221
          mcpDeviceName: /Common/abcddevlab0201.cis.mytest.net
        - managementAddress: 10.1.2.21
          mcpDeviceName: /Common/ijkldevlab0201.cis.mytest.net
        - managementAddress: 10.1.2.88
          mcpDeviceName: /Common/qrstdevlab0201.cis.mytest.net
        - managementAddress: 10.1.2.57
          mcpDeviceName: /Common/bigip1
        - managementAddress: 10.1.2.223
          mcpDeviceName: /Common/efghdevlab0201.cis.mytest.net

    mgmt_interfaces: "{{ mgmtip.json['items']|
                         map(attribute='managementAddress')|
                         list }}"
    name_addr: "{{ mgmtip.json['items']|
                   items2dict(key_name='mcpDeviceName',
                              value_name='managementAddress') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: mgmt_interfaces
    - debug:
        var: name_addr
    - debug:
        var: name_addr.values()|list
```

---

Q: ***"This is how the file looks"***

```yaml
{'/Common/abcd01.cis.mytest.net': '10.1.2.91','/Common/efgh04.cis.mytest.net':'10.1.2.221','/Common/ijkl01.cis.mytest.net': '10.1.2.221','/Common/abcd01.cis.mytest.net':'10.1.2.21',....
```

As opposed to

```yaml
/Common/abcd01.cis.mytest.net': '10.1.2.91'                                                                                                                                                    
/Common/efgh04.cis.mytest.net': '10.1.2.221'                                                                                                                                                   
/Common/ijkl01.cis.mytest.net': '10.1.2.221'                                                                                                                                                   
/Common/abcd01.cis.mytest.net': '10.1.2.21'
```

A: Use the filter *to_nice_yaml*. For example,

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/name_addr.yml
        content: |
          {{ name_addr|to_nice_yaml }}
```

gives [valid YAML](https://www.yamllint.com/)

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/name_addr.yml 
/Common/abcddevlab0201.cis.mytest.net: 10.1.2.221
/Common/bigip1: 10.1.2.57
/Common/efghdevlab0201.cis.mytest.net: 10.1.2.223
/Common/ijkldevlab0201.cis.mytest.net: 10.1.2.21
/Common/ijkllab101.cis.mytest.net: 10.1.2.91
/Common/mnoplab104.cis.mytest.net: 10.1.2.221
/Common/qrstdevlab0201.cis.mytest.net: 10.1.2.88
```

Comment: I added a complete example.

Comment: thank you for the complete example. Based on your recommendation I added both facts to the playbook. I am still seeing the same message for the mgmt _interfaces. On the other hand I see a lot more information for name_addr. Here is what I added to the playbook.

Comment: '
`- name: Set Fact
  set_fact:
    mgmt_interfaces: "{{ mgmtip.json['items']|map(attribute='managementAddress') }}"


- name: Set Fact
  set_fact:
    name_addr: "{{ mgmtip.json['items']|items2dict(key_name='mcpDeviceName',
                                                  value_name='managementAddress') }}"
`'

Comment: `
PLAY [my_dg2] ************************************
TASK [findmgmtIP : Step - 1.1 - Find management_ips] *******************************************************************************************ok: [10.1.1.20]

TASK [findmgmtIP : Set Fact] *********************ok: [10.1.1.20]

TASK [findmgmtIP : Set Fact] *********************ok: [10.1.1.20]

TASK [findmgmtIP : debug] **************************ok: [10.1.1.20] => 
  mgmt_interfaces: <generator object do_map at 0x7f0b2ec05730>

TASK [findmgmtIP : debug] **************************ok: [10.1.1.20] => 
`

Comment: while printing name_addr I see the following output
"/Common/ijkllab101.cis.mytest.net 10.1.2.91". This is closest to what I am looking for. If possible, I would like to create multiple_facts/ vars one for the hostname . For example, host_name: ijkllab101.cis.mytest.net and another one for the ipaddr: 10.1.2.91. The goal is to utilize them to output a file using jinja2 template. Would you happen to have any ideas on how to take the output of name_addr and break it into multiple facts/variables.

Comment: Use the filter *list*. I updated the examples. Upgrade your Ansible ASAP to [supported version](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html#ansible-community-changelogs) . If you still have a problem [edit] the question and provide [mre] there. Don't put the code in the comments. It isn't easy to read it here.

Comment: I rejected your edit and added an example to the answer. If you want something [edit] the question and make it [mre]. Delete the rubbish from the comments.

Comment: I'll test and report back with any updates. Earlier I was able to jerry rig a solution using bash, but this will be a better solution. Thank you again.

Comment: Please see [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). In particular, read the section *'What are comments for, and when shouldn't I comment?'*